# How to find out that current site is added in compatible list view in IE using javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, ie-compatibility-mode

I have an application which works fine in IE10 with and without compatibility mode. But there is one feature which works only in compatible mode and without compatibility mode, it has slight deviation. I can fix it if I can find out if current site in added in compatibility view list.

I check this using https://gist.github.com/jasongaylord/5733469 project. But this does not work

1. if site is an interanet site and "Display all internet site in compatible mode" option is checked.
2. if user added current site in Compatible view list by Tools->Compatibility View Setting -> Add

So is there any way to find out current website is in compatibility view or not using javascript ?

Comment: Far better to use feature detection. What feature is it that you are having issues with?

Comment: No.  The contents of the CVL are not available to JavaScript--at least not through a documented API.